# CakePHP auth controllername

Tags: cakephp

I have the following Auth Component:

```
public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'Veranstalter',
                'action' => 'login',
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'Veranstalter',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'ID' => 'ID', //Default is 'username' in the userModel
                        'Password' => 'Passwort'  //Default is 'password' in the userModel
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

As you can see, I want to use my Controller "Veranstalter" (I HAVE to use non-english words)

When I want to Login,
The Controller Veranstalter**s**Controller couldn't be found.

How do I solve this?

---

My Form Looks like this:

```
<h2>
    Login
</h2>
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('Veranstalter', array('action' => 'login')); 
?>
<table class="input">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="15">
        <col width="75">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Veranstalter Nummer
        </th>

        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('ID',array('type'=>'text','label'=>false)); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Passwort
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('Passwort',array('label'=>false)); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Login
        </th>
        <th>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end('Login');?>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using (so we can set the correct links to the book in an answer if usefull...)

Comment: `I HAVE to use non-english words` why's that? Note that routes disassociate the code from the url. I.e. if the reason is "I need veranstalter in the url", while naming the controller like that works, you don't _have_ to name your controller that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The url is wrong

The auth component uses the `loginAction` config variable [exactly as configured](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L365):

```
protected function _unauthenticated(Controller $controller) {
    ...
    $controller->redirect($this->loginAction);
```

Logically therefore, if the url you are looking at is not the url in the Auth component config, it is not responsible.

### The form action is wrong

This code for the login form:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Veranstalter', array('action' => 'login'));
```

Will generate this markup:

```
<form ... action="/veranstalters/login">
                               ^
```

Because [that's how Form::create works](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::create). The first parameter is the name of a *model*, and if no url is specified in the options, [the model name is inflected to know the name of the controller](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L389-L396).

The simplest solution is therefore to specify the url in the form options:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Veranstalter', array('url' => '/veranstalter/login'));
```

This will generate the right url:

```
<form ... action="/veranstalter/login">
                              ^
```

Comment: My Login-Form is shown correctly, but if I click onto my "Login" Button, I'm redirected to VeranstalterSController, not VeranstalterController

Comment: As I said, the redirection to my Login-Form is correct. But When I click onto my Login button in the form. I get this redirection to Veranstalters and not Veranstalter.

Comment: The Form is now there.

Comment: You still haven't answered [my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904879/cakephp-auth-controllername/32907637?noredirect=1#comment53642610_32904879). Routes would also have solved the problem you've asked about. Nonetheless I've answered your question.

Comment: Thank you very much :) The URL key was the solution :)