# CakePHP Login does not work

Tags: php, cakephp

My Login Form does Show up, but when I click on my Login Button, nothing happens.
I just land onto my Login form again and again.
`$this->request->data` Returns an empty Array.

`$this->Auth->data` Returns NULL

This is my View (login.ctp):
http://pastebin.com/aW6YSTQx

```
<?php 
if($this->Session->check('Message.auth')) $this->Session->flash('auth');  
echo $this->Form->create('Veranstalter', array('action' => 'login','url'=>'/veranstalter/login','method'=>'post')); 
?>
<h2>
    Login
</h2>
<table class="input">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="15">
        <col width="75">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Veranstalter Nummer
        </th>

        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('ID',array('type'=>'text','label'=>false)); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Passwort
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('Passwort',array('label'=>false)); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Login
        </th>
        <th>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end('Login');?>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my Controller:
http://pastebin.com/Zk4g11AK

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of VeranstalterController
 *
 * @author nilsg
 */
class VeranstalterController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('Veranstalter', 'Land', 'Veranstaltungen', 'Tagungsstaette');
    public $layout = 'main';
    public $helpers = array('Form');
    public $components = array('Flash',
        'Auth','Session');

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter(); {
            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'Veranstalter','action'=>'login');
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'Veranstalter','action'=>'index');
            $this->Auth->logoutAction = array('controller'=>'Veranstalter','action'=>'login');
            $this->Auth->userModel = 'Veranstalter';
            $this->Auth->allow =array('index');
            $this->Auth->fields = array('username'=>'ID','password'=>'Passwort');
        }
    }

    function index() {
        $this->set('Veranstalter', $this->Veranstalter->find('all', array('recursive' => 4)));
    }

    function add() {
        $this->set('laender', $this->Land->find('list'));
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->Veranstalter->validates()) {
                $this->Veranstalter->create();
                if ($this->Veranstalter->save($this->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Der Antrag wurde gespeichert.');
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Veranstalter->setFlash('Der Antrag konnte nicht angelegt werden.');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function login() {
       if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

    function edit($id = null) {
        $this->set('laender', $this->Land->find('list'));

        $this->Veranstalter->id = $id;
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->Veranstalter->read();
        } else {
            if ($this->Veranstalter->save($this->data)) {

                $this->Session->setFlash('Der Antrag wurde gespeichert');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }

    function delete($id = null) {
        $this->Veranstalter->delete($id, false);
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

    function logout() {

        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

}

?>
```

Most tutorials don't explain how the Login works. It just magically happens in the tutorials.
My cakePHP Book doesn't implement a `login()` function at all, it stays empty.

I'm using CakePHP 2.7.

Comment: Your question will be better received if you **put the code in the question**,  say what version of CakePHP you are using [as you were also asked with your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904879/cakephp-auth-controllername#comment53642270_32904879), and give a bit more detail than "it doesn't work" - if you have no further details you need to debug sufficiently to be able to say what's happening before asking a question. "Here's my code, what's wrong with it?" is not a question most readers feel like answering.

Comment: I'm absolutely new to CakePHP and I can't even tell, **what**'s not working

Answer (score 2):

you have passed data in the

```
$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)
```

It must be a blank. like below:

```
$this->Auth->login();
```